# custom content type column ordering is ignored on forms

Tags: 2010, content-type, form

This is for SharePoint 2010. I have two custom content types which I have added to a Calendar list. For each of the custom content types, I have adjusted the column ordering, as part of editing the content type. I have a Calendar list and have added the two content types to the list. The list itself displays the columns in a mostly-alphabetical order, with no means of rearranging the order. When adding a new item to the list, based on one of the two content types, the form displays the columns according to the list's column ordering, and not that of the content type.

Is there a way to adjust the ordering of the columns in the list, or in the disp/add/edit forms?

Additional Info: I tried creating a new Custom List, and added one of my custom content types to it. Still could not sort the columns, and the list's column ordering did not match the content type's ordering. Argh. I tried creating a new Calendar list, and the same thing. For whatever reason, for me at least, when adding a custom Content Type to a list, the list's column ordering gets stuck as an alphabetical list of the content type's columns, with "Created By" and "Modified By" appended to the end.

Comment: Are you using VS to define content type and list definition?

Comment: No. Purely via the Site Collection Administrator.

Comment: Did you add *manually* site columns into list? Have you tried to reorder columns in list's content type?

Comment: I did not add site columns to the list. I did all the site column additions to the site content types. The list contains no columns that I directly added; they're all from the site content types, or are the built-in "Created By", "Modified By".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have created custom forms for this list using SPD. Once these forms are created, re-ordering the list columns doesn't get reflected in these SPD forms. You have to update the forms to change the order or re-create these forms.

Comment: I have not created custom forms. I actually tried to see if I could create an InfoPath form instead, but that isn't an option when working with Calendar lists.

Comment: Designer is better! You can just create a new forms with SPD. How did you confirm if there are no custom forms? If you have not checked if the custom forms exist using SPD, i recommend you do it!